# How to push only true values to an empty array

Tags: javascript

I have variables assigned to values as:

```
let x = 5;
let y = 17;
let z = 0;

const newArr = [];
```

Here I am trying to push the `x, y, x` values if they aren't falsy values

I am doing as:

```
if(x){
  newArr.push(x);
}
if(y){
  newArr.push(y);
}
if(z){
  newArr.push(z);
}
```

May I know more efficient way to do this, TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might put all the variables into *another* array, then filter that array:

```js
let x = 5;
let y = 17;
let z = 0;
const newArr = [x, y, z].filter(Boolean);
console.log(newArr);
```